# polib как работать с библиотекой

Tags: python, python-3.x, gettext

есть код

```
import polib
po = polib.pofile('traveler.po')
for entry in po:
    print (entry.msgid, entry.msgstr)
    variable_to_translate = entry.msgid
    translated_variable = entry.msgstr
po.save('/path/to/newfile.po')
```

не пойму как записать значение  в entry.msgstr . что то типа entry.msgstr.write() не нашел .
Прошу прощения если вопрос глупый только учу питон3

Comment: Если нужно записать в msgstr, то так и попробуйте `entry.msgstr = "перевод"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, нужно найти текст "Translation" и добавить к нему перевод "Перевод":

```
import polib

po = polib.pofile('traveler.po')

# Ищем запись с нужным текстом
entry = po.find("Translation")
if entry is None:
    print("Не найдено")
else:
    # Добавляем перевод
    entry.msgstr = "Перевод"

# Сохраняем:
po.save('newfile.po')
```

Почему-то информации по всем методам в [документации](https://polib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) нет, смотрел исходник модуля: https://github.com/izimobil/polib/blob/master/polib.py

Comment: не работает ска(

Comment: У меня работает. Вы что-то не так делаете.

Comment: Возможно вы пытаетесь сохранить файл в папку, для записи в которую нужны административные права (в корень диска или в Program Files, под Windows, например).

Comment: спасибо все работает , руки из ж просто )))